# Export SAS dataset with factors as characters

Tags: csv, sas

I have a dataset in SAS with lots and lots of formats. When I export to csv all of the formats go away, and I am left with just numbers. When I export to Stata, many of my formats are preserved, but some of them are lost (I believe any formats with negative values or decimals will fail, but I am not entirely sure).

This doesn't seem overly difficult, but I can't seem to find a way to simply export to CSV (or any other output) my data with formatted variables as characters. How can I do this?

Regards

Comment: How did you export to CSV? If the formats are attached to the variables then the formatted values should written to the CSV file.

Comment: I exported the data using the export data drop down menu.

Comment: Are you using SAS with Display Manager or SAS Enterprise Guide?  or Perhaps even SAS/Studio?  I think that the gui tools might do different things.  Also what tool are you using to view the CSV file. Excel has a nasty habit of converting text in CSV files to numbers or dates if you are not careful in how you open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't appear to be SAS default behaviour. Use a proc export instead of the menu and check your results.

```
proc format;
value age_fmt
0 - 10 =  "Young"
11 - 13 = "Teen"
13 - high = "Old";
run;

data class;
set sashelp.class;
age_formatted=age;
format age_formatted age_fmt.;
run;

proc export data=class outfile='/folders/myfolders/class.csv' replace dbms=csv;
run;
```